# Audio recording issue in IOS chrome browser using HTML5 media capture

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, google-chrome

I want to record audio using html5 media capture
i am using this

```
<input name="FileInput" id="FileInput" type="file" accept="audio/*" capture="microphone" value="Start Recording" class="custom-file-input" />
```

this is working fine for desktop browsers and android browser like chrome.

But in IOS chrome it opens video recording options. But it is not working.

In IOS safari it records video instead of Audio.

I have search and found that some other are facing this same issue. But i need to know any alternative which solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623118/safari-and-recording-audio-html-media-capture-getusermedia/

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS does not currently support audio only capture through HTML Media Capture. It supports only photo and video capture.

Tested with iOS 6 - 10.3 .

I gave a more detailed answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/43737156/813988